# How to convert foreach loop with a switch statement into LINQ

Tags: linq, foreach

I have following:

```
  foreach (var x in items)
                {
                    switch (x.name)
                    {
                        case firstname1:
                        case firstname2:
                        case firstname3:                            .
                            x.Value =  somemethodcall;
                            break;
                    }
                }
```

`switch` has about 15 different values to check against. The `x` has 3 properties: `name`, `value` and `enum` constant to check `x.name` against. `items` is a collection of `x` objects with many `enum` constants, but I only want to find certain ones and apply same method to alter the `x.value` property.

Is it possible to use linq to convert my foreach as one liner?

Comment: LINQ is for querying/generating new collections, not for modifying existing objects. If you wanted to create new `x` from the old `x`, you might use LINQ, but not if you want to modify in place. LINQ is also slower than using a regular loop.

Comment: What is the third property in `x`?

Comment: the third property is enum type.
public enum fields {
        firstName1,
        firstName2,
        firstName3          
        .
        .
        .
        .
        }
        
        so the switch(x.name)
        {
        case fields.firstname1:
        case fields.firstname2:
        x.value=methodcall()
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
items.ToList().Where(x => x.name == firstname1 || x.name == firstname2).ForEach(x => x.Value =  somemethodcall)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is long because of switch instead of foreach.

```
switch (x.name)
{
    case firstname1:
    case firstname2:
    case firstname3:
```

can be written as

```
var names = new []{firstname1, firstname2, firstname3};
if (names.Contains(x.name))
```

foreach itself can be written as

```
items.Select(SetValueByName);
```

where

```
string[] names = new []{firstname1, firstname2, firstname3};
TypeOfX SetValueByName(TypeOfX x)
{
    if(names.Contains(x.name))
    {
         x.Value = somemethodcall;
    }
    return x;
}
```

if the optimization doesn't apply to your scenario, just

```
TypeOfX SetValueByName(TypeOfX x)
{
    .. original switch statement
    return x;
}
```

Comment: thanks. My requirements need to do in place update of the property for certain items in the list. Having where to select them and apply foreach extension made it work.